# Cannot select project name when creating new session bean in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ejb, session-bean

While creating a new session bean in eclipse for an ejb project, I can't seem to select the project name and hence cannot create a session bean.

[image: screenshot]

I'm using JBoss 7.1 ,ejb module 3.1 and jdk 1.8.

Comment: What happens after you right-click over the *src/main/java* source folder of **your project** and select *New > Other > EJB > Session Bean (EJB 3.x)*? Does the project name appears filled?

Comment: @arbeiro I'm not sure what you meant by "your" project but I right clicked on my ejb project and the window in above screenshot appears after New > Other > EJB > Session Bean (EJB 3.x). Strangely, new session bean option does not appear directly(like it does in video tutorials) after clicking right click but after clicking "Other" and searching for it,  it does appear. And yes, the project name is not filled in every session bean I try to create regardless of the type of project.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have solved this problem. But I also meet this problem today. The reason is that the project need to include "EJB Module". Just right-click on your project that need to add session bean. chose "Properities", then chose "Project Facets". Make sure "EJB Module" is selected. Then click "ok" to confirm your change. That's all.[Project Facets view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/819Xo.jpg)